# Is there a word to describe a sentence in which two positive words are used?

Tags: phrases

An oxymoron is a figure of speech in which contradictory terms appear in conjunction with one another. Can there be a figure of speech in which similar compatible terms appear in conjunction with one another?

For example, how would I describe the following sentence?

Nice should be great.

Nice being the location, but also a compliment. Play on words? Comedic effect?

Feel like there isn't one and idiom or a proverb doesn't quite fit.

Comment: This isn't really analogous to an oxymoron. You're not describing the same thing with two different qualities; you're using a word ("Nice") that has two different meanings.

Comment: 'Nice' and 'great' might be positive, but they are feeble decriptions that don't say much.

Comment: No, there isn't such a word, because there is no such thing as a "positive word". Negatives exist, but they're special in many ways; and few of them have "opposites".

Comment: The usual definition of 'oxymoron' is a tersely worded paradox: an **apparent** contradiction, not a true contradiction in terms (the terms taken individually seem incompatible).

Answer (score 1):

It is a somewhat typical "pun" ([from M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pun)):

> the usually humorous use of a word in such a way as to suggest two or more of its meanings or the meaning of another word similar in sound

It takes advantage of the fact that "Nice" and "nice", while not exactly homophones, are homographs. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun) notes:

> A pun, also rarely known as paronomasia, is a form of word play that exploits multiple meanings of a term, or of similar-sounding words, for an intended humorous or rhetorical effect. These ambiguities can arise from the intentional use of homophonic, **homographic**, metonymic, or figurative language. (emphasis added)